Second Generation P-values in the Context of Statistical Evidence and Sample Size
I am currently doing research on statistical analysis, and I have come across the concepts of Second Generation P-values (SGPVs) introduced by Blume et al. I understand that these are used to determine the statistical significance of data, but I am having some difficulty understanding how they relate to statistical evidence and sample size.
SGPVs are designed to provide a direct measure of the compatibility between the observed data and a specified statistical model. Which seems to address some of the criticisms of P-values. As I read through, I have these questions:

How can this concept influence the sample size? We all know that, traditionally, we mostly calculate sample size using p values.
Now, if SGPVs address the challenges of p values, how can we also estimate the sample size based on SGPVs? Any idea how we can calculate the sample sizes?
I am aware of the power of the SGPVs given in Blume et al.'s paper, but I was trying to see if I could calculate the sample size based on the power function, but it seems n is non-linear, making it difficult to use n as a subject for sample size calculation. I would be glad if someone had a fair idea of how to use the power function for calculating the sample size.

In the context of your contribution, if one has an idea of using an r function to achieve the above results, they are welcome to help me understand this concept and apply it to my research.
References:
Second-generation p-values: Improved rigor, reproducibility, & transparency in statistical analyses.
Supplementing or Replacing p:
An Introduction to Second-Generation p-Values

Given that the SGPV is an attempt to re-do the significance test and hypothesis test frameworks, it might be sensible to switch from power calculations for sample size determination to expected p-values. See section 2.5 in this chapter for details and discussion: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286

If you are interested in the relationship between p-values and statistical evidence then my ArXived paper on the topic is still one of very few explorations of the topic: https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0081

@MichaelLew, thank you for the references to look at.

"We all know that, traditionally, we mostly calculate sample size using p values." Is that so? I doubt it. Sample size calculations are pre data, p-values are computed post data.

Yeah, I came down to comments to ask about the same issue as Christian. Can you explain how you're computing sample size using p-values?

@Glen_b Likely the sample size is determined with a value of $\alpha$ specified so that p<$\alpha$ is the determination of 'significant'.

I don't follow. That's still not a calculation of sample size that is using a p-value, it would be using a p-value for the test but not the sample size calculation. I'd like to hear from the OP on what they're doing when they say that.

@Glen_b To calculate the necessary sample size for desired power you need to specify the effect size expected and the $\alpha$ that will be used. Substitue "p-value" for "$\alpha$".

@MichaelLew ...but that's not the same thing (although in all likelihood it's what is meant).

"the statistical significance of data" is somewhat meaningless. Contrast with something like "the statistical significance of data with respect to a specific hypothesis about the distribution from which they were drawn."
